# Defining discrete stochastic integrals in infinite sum for uniformly bounded simple processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

This is a lemma from Rogers and Williams' Diffusions, Markov Processes, and Martingales.

Here, $H$ is a uniformly bounded simple process defined by an infinite sum. Defining
$$H \bullet M(t) = \sum Z_{i-1}\{M(T_i \wedge t) - M(T_{i-1}\wedge t)\}$$ as in (25.1),  how can we show that $H\bullet M$ is in $\mathcal{M}_0^2$, which is the space of $L^2$ bounded martingales null at $0$?

I am not sure how we can deal with the infinite sum here to show martingale property and $L^2$ boundedness, in particular, how we get $E(H\bullet M)^2_\infty \le c^2 E(M_\infty^2)$. I would greatly appreciate any help.

[image]

[image]

[image]